# Rename lots of files in one click

Tags: rename

Is there any application that can rename lots of files which have the same name in them with different numbers.
For example. I want to rename, File 01.avi and  File 02.avi up to File 100.avi. Into 01.avi, 02.avi.
How do I do that?In windows or ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the given example, and generally for purposes similar to these, one usually uses a [batch renamer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_renaming). There are many of the sort, so I'd rather not give reccommendations - instead, my heartly suggestion is to read on what they do in the above article, afterwards finding one that suits your needs should be trivial.

In the above article there are also several mentioned, for both Linux and Windows.

*p.s. Just so to satisfy the "quote", I use [this one](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Screenshots.php) on Windows, and it performs beautifully. Simple, beautiful, works ... doesn't know how to make coffee. The author promised that feature in the next version.*

[image]

Comment: ... With GUIs like that, I'd rather use the command line.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams - :)) Yes, I remember it looked rather confusing to me as well when I started it the first time. But it is rather well placed, nothing unneccessary and everything on screen. There is a command line version available as well.

Comment: that reminds me of how hard it is to come up with a good ui

Comment: That's the worst UI I've ever seen!  Second Ignacio's sentiments.  I came browsing because this question is now shown as a dup of one I answered before it was closed at http://superuser.com/questions/482142/batch-rename-images-numerically with 4 lines of C shell.

Answer (score 2):

```
rename 's/^File //' File*.avi
```

Answer (score 0):

In Windows on command line: Use powershell, and its foreach and rename-to commands. There you can use all powershell functions (convert case, replace, sha-1 etc) for manipulating the names.

Windows or Ubuntu: Use Emacs' directory editor - you basically open a file listing in the editor, edit it (search/replace, whatever you like) and then you "apply" all the changes at once. (Note that if you don't like Emacs - and it is some kind of love-or-hate relationship - you might not like this solution either).