# Batch rename images numerically?

Tags: images, rename, batch-rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rename lots of files in one click](https://superuser.com/questions/151626/rename-lots-of-files-in-one-click)

I have thousands of images that I wish to batch rename numerically.

The issue is all the dozens of images I have saved have osbscure filenames like in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3FqU.jpg)

I want the output(s) to be something like: 0001, 0002, or 001, 002, etc

What would be the best way to achieve/do this?

Comment: See also [this](http://superuser.com/questions/467755/command-script-to-copy-files-with-certain-ext-which-may-have-the-same-name) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248393/windows-batch-file-to-copy-and-keep-duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

You're on Windows, so you could do it this way with [Hamilton C shell](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Cshell.htm):

```
@ n = 1
foreach i ( *.jpg )
   mv $i $printf("%04d.jpg", n++)
end
```

The [free demo version](http://hamiltonlabs.com/Demo.htm) is all you need.  (Full disclosure:  I'm the author.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming pure Windows (i.e., no Cygwin, et al.) and that you don't want to or can't install anything to do it with, I'd suggest using a Visual Basic script to do the job. You might try something like:

```
 targetDir = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
 WScript.Echo "Operating on files in " + targetDir
 Set fsh = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set targetFiles = fsh.GetFolder(targetDir).Files
 ZeroPadWidth = Len(targetFiles.Count)
 FileNumber   = 0
 For Each File In targetFiles
   FileNumber = FileNumber + 1
   NewName = targetDir & "\"
   For I = 1 To ZeroPadWidth - Len(FileNumber)
     NewName = NewName & "0"
   Next
   NewName = NewName & FileNumber
   WScript.Echo "Renaming " & targetDir & "\" & File.Name & ": " & NewName
   File.Move(NewName)
 Next
```

Put that into a file, e.g. "rename.vbs"; then, call it from the command line, with the target directory as the sole argument, like this:

```
 c:\Users\Username\Desktop> cscript rename.vbs "c:\target\directory"
```

It will produce filenames which are ordered numerically and left-padded with zeroes; if you have a directory with a thousand files in it, you'll get names ranging from 0001, 0002...0999, 1000.

No warranty, but it should do what you need. If it doesn't, let me know. (And make a safe copy of the target directory just in case; I've tested this a bit, and it should be OK, but there's always the possibility of the bug I didn't catch.)

Hope this helps! (If it does, I hope you'll take Shinrai's point about accept rates to heart.)